# Clear tomcat work and webapps before start from init system

Tags: linux, tomcat

Is it a good practice to deleate the `webapps` and `work` content before starting the tomcat in init.d or systemctl script?

Something like this:

```
...
case "$1" in
    start)
          rm -rf $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/* 
          rm -rf $CATALINA_BASE/work/* 
          /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
          RETVAL=$?
          echo
          [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/tomcat
          ;;
    stop)
          # Stop daemons.
          echo -n "Shutting down Tomcat: "
          /usr/local/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
          RETVAL=$?
          echo
          [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/tomcat
          ;;
    restart)
          $0 stop
          $0 start
          ;;
    condrestart)
         [ -e /var/lock/subsys/tomcat ] && $0 restart
         ;;
    status)
          status tomcat
          ;;
    *)
          echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
          exit 1
  esac
```

The application is installed with `context.xml` file in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Definitely not the `webapps` folder - you would have to redeploy your webapps. And the `work` folder does not make much sense, there are stored the compiled JSP pages (in both `.java` and `.class` form), and deleting it would mean they have to be compiled again.

Deleting the `work` folder makes sense when you are debugging JSPs, and are not sure, if Tomcat really uses the newest version. Otherwise I do not see much sense in it.

Comment: Agreed with Josef's remarks.  WebApps you would have to re-publish.  WORK and TEMP are OK, but can cause delays in cycling your server.  Some apps you can reload context, but in the case of WORK/TEMP, you will need to restart services.